# PHP Json String decode

Tags: php, json, string

It's my first question, I'm working on this problem for a long time, but I don't know where it is.

I want to read a Json string from a file, (and it does) but when I use "*json_decode*" does not work, I tried to copy the file content into a variable, and it works great, I cant understand why, can someone help.

Thanks!

**Here you have the code:**

```
<HTML>
<p>-JSON STRING (From File)-</p>
<?PHP
    $jsonStr = "";
    $jsonStr =$jsonStr . file_get_contents("./Config.json");
    echo "Json String: " . $jsonStr;

?>
<p>-JSON DATA-</p>
<?PHP
    $jsonDec = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
    $name = $jsonDec['config'][0]['nombre'];
    echo "Json data: " . $name;

    echo "</br>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
?>

<p>-JSON STRING (From var)-</p>
<?PHP
    $jsonStr = '{ "config" :[ {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"} ] } ';
    echo "Json String: " . $jsonStr;
?>
<p>-JSON DATA-</p>
<?PHP
    $jsonDec = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
    $name = $jsonDec['config'][0]['name'];

    echo "Json data: " .  $name;
?>
```

**And here is the result I get:**

```
-JSON STRING (From File)-
```

Json String: { "config" :[ {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"} ] }

-JSON DATA-
Json data:

-JSON STRING (From var)-
Json String: { "config" :[ {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"} ] }

-JSON DATA-
Json data: Eduvi

Comment: Dont know why you are using $jsonStr here `$jsonStr . file_get`, but change it to `$jsonStr =trim(file_get_contents("./Config.json"));`

Comment: Issue/Bug is `'nombre'`  in the first block, that field does not exists in the json string, second block uses `'name'`. Always debug with `var_dump($jsonDec);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Config.json is a encoded in UTF-8 ([with BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)), the json_decode function will fail and return NULL.

You can fix this by trimming the BOM from your $jsonStr string:

```
$jsonStr = trim(file_get_contents("config.json"), "\xEF\xBB\xBF");
```

Aside from that, you aren't addressing an existing value (*see vv01f's answer for that*)

Best of luck!

Comment: Buah!, thank's you a lot, it works perfectly now, next time I'll pay more attention on this.
I realised that in Notepad++ you can encode it automatically in UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

- `Undefined index: nombre in /tmp/test.php on line 10` => means you call an index that is not there, as you can see in the data yourself; if it was, it will show the contained value

input file `site.txt`:

```
{ "config" :[ {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"} ] }
```

php code 'test.php':

```
<?php

    echo("\n-JSON STRING (From File)-\n");
    $jsonStr = "";
    $jsonStr = trim( file_get_contents("./site.txt") ); // fix 
    echo "Json String: " . $jsonStr."\n";

    echo("\n-JSON DATA-\n");
    $jsonDec = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
    $name = $jsonDec['config'][0]['nombre']; //index nombre does not exist, if it is 'name', then it works
    echo "Json data: " . $name;

    echo "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";

    echo("\n-JSON STRING (From var)-\n");
    $jsonStr = '{ "config" :[ {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"} ] } ';
    echo "Json String: " . $jsonStr."\n";
    echo("\n-JSON DATA-\n");
    $jsonDec = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
    $name = $jsonDec['config'][0]['name'];

    echo "Json data: " .  $name."\n";
?>
```

running it on cli with `php test.php`:

```
-JSON STRING (From File)-
Json String: { "config" :[ {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"} ] }

-JSON DATA-
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: nombre in /tmp/test.php on line 10
Json data:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-JSON STRING (From var)-
Json String: { "config" :[ {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"} ] }

-JSON DATA-
Json data: Eduvi
```

output after fixing 'name':

```
-JSON STRING (From File)-
Json String: { "config" :[ {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"} ] }

-JSON DATA-
Json data: Eduvi
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-JSON STRING (From var)-
Json String: { "config" :[ {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"}, {"name" : "Eduvi", "link" : "LINKURL"} ] }

-JSON DATA-
Json data: Eduvi
```

- also try to take the same input as I do here for testing ;)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to translate the variable name, but still not working.

Comment: I think you did not execute my code, otherwise you would have the same result ;) here it works after "translation".

Answer (score 0):

i'm testing this example, works perfectly fine and the basic file is  ob.php

```
$jsonStr = "";
$jsonStr =$jsonStr . file_get_contents("myfile.json");
echo "Json String one : " . $jsonStr;


$jsonDec = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
$name = $jsonDec['config'][0]['name'];
echo "Json data: " . $name;

echo "</br>-------------------------";
```

after that add you json file myfile.json

```
{
    "config": [{
        "name": "Eduvi",
        "link": "LINKURL"
    }, {
        "name": "Eduvi",
        "link": "LINKURL"
    }, {
        "name": "Eduvi",
        "link": "LINKURL"
    }]
}
```

that's it to display the value of name, the first object in you array